# Saving a interval on a session variable error

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express-session

So I am using express session and socket.io express session sharing. Now it seems this error comes from express alone, it seems saving a interval to a session does this at all times. I am confused, can you not do this with express-session?

So here is where I am setting the interval, and trying to save it:

```
exports = module.exports = function (io) {

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // FIGHT CALL
    socket.on('fight mob', (mobId) => {
      var session = socket.handshake.session;

let sql = 'SELECT * FROM mobs WHERE id = ?';

      // If there is no interval, or if it is false, intiate one.
      if (session.userdata.actionInterval === undefined ||
          session.userdata.actionInterval === false) {

        db.query(sql, mobId).then(results => {
          session.userdata.actionInterval = setInterval(() => {
            battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
            session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
          }, 6000);
          session.userdata.intervalTime = Date.now();
          session.userdata.autos = 5;
          session.save();
          battle.battle(socket, results[0], session);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at hash (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express-session/index.js:580:19)
    at Session.save (/home/kogadmin/www/node_modules/express-session/index.js:380:21)
    at db.query.then.results (/home/kogadmin/www/io/fight.io.js:30:19)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

The problem here is: I have absolutely no idea what or why this is causing it. It will even do it if I just try a console inside the interval and removing the DB query. I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Even if it didn't get an error, it probably doesn't make sense to save an interval in a session variable. Intervals refer to transient data about the current process, and might not be valid in a future call.

Comment: I kind of need it save to a session. This whole game revolves around an interval, or a timed function and it needs to save to their session. I know theres a way to do this, even if it is not the method of intervals.

Comment: Something you're putting in the session can't be converted to JSON.  You need to first find out which item in the session is causing this circular structure error either by examining everything in the session or by just trial/error removing things to see when the error goes away.  It might be the interval or it might be something else.  If it is the interval, there are ways to keep a list of intervals (outside the session) and then store an index to the interval in the session.